# Jquery async false stopping other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Sorry I don't really know how to explain this so hopefully the code below shows what needs to happen.

I click a button and it should hide `$(this).hide();` and turn to a spinner `$(this).hide();` Then an ajax function either reconcile or unreconcile is to run and after completion the button is shown again with the appropriate styling. The ajax functions needs to be `async: false` to only do one at a time but when this is set the spinner stops showing. If I remove the `async: false` then the spinner will show but allows users to click multiple lines and data can get mixed up.

```
// click on the button to verify/unverify the transaction
$('.txn_check').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.recon-saving').show();

    if($(this).hasClass('txn_verified')){
        unreconcile($(this));
    } else {
        reconcile($(this));
    }
});

function reconcile(txnObj){
    {literal}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: '/accounting/bank/do-reconcile-transaction',
        data: {bank_account_id: bank_account_id,
                     accounting_entry_id: txnObj.data('accounting-entry-id'),
                     accounting_journal_key_type: txnObj.data('accounting-journal-key-type'),
                     accounting_journal_id: txnObj.data('accounting-journal-id'),
                     txn_id: txnObj.data('txn-id'),
                     txn_value_in: txnObj.data('txn-value-in'),
                     txn_value_out: txnObj.data('txn-value-out'),
                     verified_balance: $('#verified_balance').val()},
        success: function(result){
            var result = $.parseJSON(result);
            if(result.result == 'SUCCESS'){
                mark_verified(txnObj);
                // update_balance_rows();
                $('#verified_balance').val(result.verified_balance);
                $('#verified_balance_text').text(display_number(result.verified_balance));
                get_difference();
            } else {
                mark_unverified(txnObj);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
    {/literal}
}
```

Comment: This is why `async: false` is bad practice - it runs on the UI thread and blocks other actions from occurring until the request has completed. You've not explained fully why you need to run this in sync, but I would guess that keeping an array of the requests made and using `$.when` to execute a callback when they have all completed would be a better pattern to use.

Comment: But I thought it wouldnt be affected since the hiding is being called first then the ajax. the end result styleing works ok though.

Comment: It all depends on how quick the renderer updates. The point stands though, `async: false` is the issue to be resolved.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough see, while you did set the style first, you didn't clear the callstack before sending the ajax request, therefore the event loop never ran the browser renderer, thus the change in style wasn't rendered until after it was changed back.

Comment: Disable the button until the active process is complete. That should do the trick, at least from the UI perspective. Is is a read-only operation or it does have side-effects?

Comment: @KevinB how do I do this then? If push comes I can leave it as is but would like the spinner to show the user something is happening.

Comment: Since the spinner only spins when the browser does a render, it will be unable to spin while the sync ajax request is in process. Getting it to show  likely won't help your cause due to this.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough You cannot having any spinner running BECAUSE you are setting ajax request to sync. Use async request, problem solved

Comment: @PierceMcGeough you need to make the requests async. If you can give some more detail on exactly why that currently doesn't work for you we can guide you on how to re-arrange your logic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there are many rows to un/reconcile and if users click fast on multiple items off and on then the front end calculations can be put off. Async:false made sure all get done one at a time without stopping clicking the next one.

Comment: In that case you could make the requests async and have a global flag to state whether or not a request is in progress. You can stop any new requests until that flag is reset in the `success` or `fail` handler. This would allow the UI to update, but stop multiple requests.

Comment: Is there much change in my code needed for that. I kinda understand what you are saying but not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should set request async, then use:

```
$('.txn_check').click(function(){
     $('.txn_check').prop('disabled', true); // avoid any click while request pending
     $(this).hide();
     //...
});
```

Now the ajax request:

```
function reconcile(txnObj){    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        // all others request options here...
    }).always(function(){ // or use complete option of ajax request
         $('.txn_check').prop('disabled', false); //reenable other buttons
    });
}
```

This is the basic idea, not sure in your specific case how do you wish to hanlde it.